# How to pass a Date object from Flex to a JSP Servlet?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, servlets, actionscript

I am passing some parameters as POST to a Servlet from my Flex WebApplication. I am able to pass and retrieve strings properly.

I used `new Date().getTime()` in my flex code and tried passing the timestamp variable hoping to parse it at the servlet and convertit into a `java.util.Date` object. But i am getting a NumberFormatException when i try to parse the variable from the string that i got from `request.getParameter`.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not converting String to long in Java IF so Please try

```
String strDateinmilliseconds = request.getAttribute("FlexMilliseconds");

long dateinmilliseconds = Long.valueOf(strDateinmilliseconds);

Date resultdate = new Date(dateinmilliseconds);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: Yes it did. I tried to parse the milliseconds using `Integer.parseInt` The snippet that you provided is giving me the required output. thank you.